# NavigationView on both side

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I need to open navigation view on both side with different menu.. Also I need to change navigation icon (Currently with three horizontal line). This is better if I can open the `nav_view` and `na_view2` with separate button clicks, these buttons are available in my toolbar, or I need to know how can I set separate icons on both side?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer1" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get buttons from toolbar by following lines,

```
Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
Button btnEnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnd);
```

and while click the start button we can open and hide left drawer by following listener,

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        else drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
});
```

and while click the end button we can open and hide right drawer by following listener,

```
btnEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        else drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }
});
```

And our `onBackPressed` method will be

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This also used to close the drawers if those is in open state.